# Broken Python 2.7 GAE installation causing ImportError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, windows-7, python-2.7

Gae sdk was running without errors (using 2.7 and webapp2), but stopped suddenly. Now I cannot even get the example from [the getting started page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) to work.

I've done clean installs of both python and gae, no dice.  I've tried different versions of python 2.7 (2.7.3, activestate 2.7.2) and gae (1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6), but I am still getting the ImportError below.

Additional information:

1. I can import the _socket module in cmd or python shell without errors.
2. I have the exact same problem on my laptop.
3. My girlfriend's Vista machine runs the example code fine.
4. I do not have Python 2.5 installed, I am guessing GAE is referencing the python25.dll file in T:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\

> ```
> >     2012-05-22 12:56:59 Running command: "['T:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'T:\\Program Files
> > (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py',
> > '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080',
> > u'T:\\Users\\Wyatt\\Desktop\\helloworld']"
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "T:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 126, in <module>
> >         run_file(__file__, globals())
> >       File "T:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 122, in run_file
> >         execfile(script_path, globals_)
> >       File "T:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py",
> > line 157, in <module>
> >         from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
> >       File "T:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line
> > 41, in <module>
> >         import mimetypes
> >       File "T:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 29, in <module>
> >         import urllib
> >       File "T:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
> >         import socket
> >       File "T:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
> >         import _socket
> >     ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
> >     2012-05-22 12:56:59 (Process exited with code 1)
> ```

Comment: Is it possible that you have an earlier version of Python installed on the machine, and that it's in the PATH?

Comment: I've checked, there's nothing in any PATH variables that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Weird that `python25.dll` is getting into the mix. I don't know enough about Windows7 to explain that.

Comment: I encountered this issue myself recently and managed to get it fixed by removing the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: @KevinP I encountered the same problem, but I can't find PYTHONPATH.. where did you find it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and fixed by removing PYTHONPATH from from environment variables. I am installing SimpleCV and the problem come from it.

Go to System => Advanced System Parameters => environment variables, then in user variables look for PYTHONPATH and remove it. Restart Google AppEngine and it should work.

Comment: If we remove the pythonpath from user variables the google app engine launcher wont run as it requires python

Comment: you should remove it from user variables and keep `C:\python27` in system path. I did it and it's working just fine.